# Wiring breakers

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, breaker-box

I left extra wire in the box in case I needed to move to another breaker do I have to strip the entire length of the orange wire or can I just strip parts of it?

Comment: are you talking about the cover material on Romex ?

Comment: Yes the protective cover.

Comment: If you do strip them please bond the ground wire to the grounding terminal  you dont want it moving arround where it could contact anything live

Answer (score 6):

You should remove the cable jacket (the outer covering of the cable), so that only about 1/2" - 1/4" is inside the box. The wires themselves, should only be stripped back enough to fit into the terminals.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a clamp as it enters the box other than that it dosent really matter, I usually strip them and put wire nuts then mark with the location the spare goes to